# Rewrite rules for subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This may seem like a silly question but I can't figure it out.

let's say I have a public_html folder with various folders like: Albatross, Blackbirds, Crows and Faqs.

I want to make it so that any traffic to Albatross/faqs.php, Blackbirds/faqs.php, Crows/faqs.php etc will see the file that is at faqs/faqs.php?bird=albatross or faqs/faqs.php?bird=crows or what have you.

If I go into the Albatross folder's .htaccess file I can do this

```
RewriteRule faqs.php$ /faqs/faqs.php?cat=albatross[QSA]
```

Which works fine, but I want to put something in the top level .htacces that works for all of them, so  tried:

```
RewriteRule faqs.php$ /faqs/faqs.php?cat=albatross[QSA]

RewriteRule /(.*)/faqs.php$ /faqs/faqs.php?cat=$1  [QSA]
```

and even

```
RewriteRule /albatross/faqs.php$ /faqs/faqs.php?cat=albatross  [QSA]
```

and various others but nothing seems to work, when I go to http://www.birdsandwhatnot.com/albatross/faqs.php I see the same file the same way it's always been.  Does the presence of an .htaccess file in the subfolder conflict with the higher up .htaccess file?

Am I missing something?

Comment: The first problem is that your server is down. :)

Comment: Haha I usually use chuckecheese.com or legitimatebusiness.ru as examples!

Comment: example.com is a good example ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small correction should do the trick

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/faqs.php$ /faqs/faqs.php?cat=$1  [QSA]
```

"/" is not being passed to parser.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is what I was going to post, except I usually go with [QSA,L] to make sure no other RewriteRules down the line cause trouble.

Comment: Thanks, but this still has no effect, I just see the original page.  I know my top level .htaccess is working though because I use it for 301's etc.  I tried it with [QSA,L] at the end also but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Make sure you have enabled rewrite engine in .htaccess

RewriteEngine on

Also make sure in your web server configuration (assuming apache) you have mod_rewrtite loaded. If you don't have access to configuration, make a simple php script, put phpinfo() then check about loaded modules.