# how do I write this rule in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have Rewrite rules written in the htaccess that is placed in the root of the domain. I've now installed a forum application in a sub-folder called 'forum' in the root directory. While I try to install that there, it is unable to install because of the rewrite rules set in the .htaccess. I looked around and found that someone suggested to use RewriteCond in the .htaccess in a way where do not apply any Rewrite rule for URL's that start with /forum. Can someone help? Not too familiar with .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you , when you need to write htaccess rules for sub-folder or sub-directory.

- [.htaccess for subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805464/htaccess-for-subfolder)
- [htaccess rewrite rule for subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837245/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-subfolder)
- [Rewrite rules for subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634048/rewrite-rules-for-subfolders)

Good luck..